# When i texture paint in 2.8 how do i add shadows to see what im painting

Tags: uv, texture-painting, shadows

When  i texture paint I like to paint on the actual object instead of the uv map but it seems that when I set up an object ready to paint its all one colour, no distinguishable features so i don't know what im painting. 
Thanks , J.H.B.W.

Comment: Are you talking about Vertex Paint? If so, you need to make sure you are not set to use Random or MatCap but use the Material overlay. If you can't see shadow at all, double check the Shadow in the Overlay settings.

Comment: I'm unsure what you're asking, could you give more detail?

Comment: when I go onto texture paint and colour the object, the whole thing is that colour, no shadows! but when i render it, it has shadows but on render view it doesn't.

Comment: What draw mode are you using, and can you share some screen shots to show us what is going on?

Answer (score 1):

When in *Texture Paint* mode and *Rendered View* go to *Overlays* on the top right.

At the bottom of the drop-down window for *Overlays* there will be a section *Texture Paint* and below it will say *Opacity*. If this is set to zero you will have full shadows on your model.

I find this makes it easier to paint directly onto the model and see where your paint is going.